# disable notifications for certain programs?

Tags: xfce, notification

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Xfce-4. I would like to use thunderbird's own notification, but activating that turns into 3 messages per new mail:

- one from Thunderbird with mail info
- one general with mail info
- one just saying "You have new mail" and "no default action".

Is it possible to exclude Thunderbird from the general notification? I would like to keep the other programs calling `xfce4-notifyd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From its source page [here](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/xfce4-notifyd), `Run xfce4-notifyd-config` to display the settings dialog. There aren't any other settings you can tune; if you do not see it in the settings dialog, it's not changeable.

Comment: As I suspected, no more configuration...thanks for your reply.